# What are the names of these food dishes?

Tags: bread

There is pizza on the bottom, but what are the names of the remaining dishes like the one with the asparagus on top of what looks like bread and then the one to the left of it with a bunch of thin sheets?

[image: http://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=Image&Name=135664.jpg]

Comment: Ah, that's much better. I have to say that the photo (without magnification) piqued my sense of the ridiculous. I thought those things on the top were baby bunnies being roasted whole!

Comment: Thinking of it again, the question is not answerable. 1) there is not enough info to go on - all we get is wild guesses. 2) if somebody does, by chance, find the correct answer, the community can't judge that. 3) They may not even be real dishes. This is a promo picture for an oven. Maybe they had prepared it with focaccia and then the photographer cried "not enough contrast here, find me something green for the picture" and the assistant spread asparagus on top. In any case, we cannot say anything more than what everybody can see.

Comment: @rumtscho With respect, I don't agree that this should be "put on hold" for the reasons stated. Yes, I concede that OP would benefit from light editing but even aspiring gastronomes and commis-chefs would be able to fathom what's going on from the photo even if the OP's terminology falls short of professional or informed standards. And I'd like to think that those of our community who have already posted answers and comments have more or less rumbled what's on the menu with the exception of the stuffed thingies on the top. Nuff said. How can I vote to rescind its current "put on hold" status?

Comment: @rumtscho And another thing, there's plenty to go on in the photo, especially when enlarged; I don't consider my comment to be a "wild guess" [sic] (If only you knew, but I am keeping stumn about my own professional background); they are most certainly "real" dishes, it's just questionable that they have any gastronomic merit; what is your evidence that its a promo pix?; the rest of your "observations" are unhelpful and wild conjecture: yes, not everyone has the ability to see what's going on in this picture. However, I think those who have made constructive comments have excellent eyesight.

Comment: Yes, my observations are conjectures - just like the answers posted. The statements which can be made based on the picture are not sufficient to name the dish. The OP already recognized that this is something bread-like with asparagus on top, merely noticing that there is some kind of yellow sauce does not define the food. At the same time, guesses like "spinach casserole" are very specific, but not at all confirmable. If the next answerer guesses that it is chicken pot pie with phyllo topping instead of biscuit, and a third says a baklava, nobody but the photog can tell who is right.

Comment: It can be any of dozens of dishes, or it could be not intended for serving (my evidence comes from knowing that in product photography, looks count more than edibility, and in appliance photography even more so). I can't say for sure that this is the case here, but neither can I dismiss the option. It is exactly this "anything is possible" situation which makes the question fun to muse about, but a bad fit for a stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those are spears of green asparagus resting on some kind of dough, pastry or bread and, **crucially,** there is a hint of a yellow sauce that has been drizzled over the asparagus and come to rest between the asparagus and the underlying pastry/dough/bread. I am hazarding an informed guess that the sauce is a classic *hollandaise* sauce which is one of two or three ways of serving asparagus as a dish in itself. It maybe termed asparagus *Benedict* as in eggs Benedict. *The sauce is not made in an oven so I remain cautious. The layers on the left look like *filo* pastry.

*Larousse Gastronomique* is the "bible" for these sort of things.

Comment: Oh, deary me! I have forgotten to mention that the yellow sauce on and under the asparagus maybe butter or clarified butter. Melted butter is another classic "sauce"  served with asparagus as a dish, usually a starter. You will need to magnify the picture to see the yellow sauce.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what each dish actually is, but I'm willing to make some educated guesses from what I can see.

The thin sheets look like phyllo dough - some kind of casserole or pie topped with sheets of dough.  It might be a spinach casserole, they're fairly popular, but I can't see beneath the layers of dough.  It's topped with green leaves as a garnish, maybe basil or something - though they look very pale, maybe one of the lettuce mix greens instead?  Which makes me think it's a vegetable-based filling.

The asparagus thing, just looks like asparagus laid over sets of bread sticks (I can see they look separated on the side), with a layer of cheese and herbs, maybe some kind of oil or butter in between. It vaguely reminds me of some pics of asparagus tarts, but that's not a great fit - the asparagus is too thickly laid and doesn't look like there's enough binding it to the bread (the cheese and herbs layer looks pretty thin), the bread sticks are too fluffy, and the bread sticks and asparagus are laid cross grain - if separated by bread stick the asparagus would be chopped into little bits and probably fall right off everywhere.  Probably tasty, but it looks messy.  In any case, you could probably layer something like that up and try it.

The top things look like bread rolls - hollowed out and stuffed with something (maybe a hot dip or filling), with strips of red and orange bell peppers used for garnish.  I would probably go with a creamy veggie dip, to go with the bell peppers - especially as I can see what looks like bits of green and tan and pale yellow in the mix, and browned on top, but you could fit anything in there and not much change the looks - even something like sandwich fillings, chicken salad or the like.

And, yeah, that's definitely pizza on the bottom, with two kinds of olives, tomatoes, and pepperoni.

Comment: What has me scratching my head is the oven situation for the asparagus. If that hint of a yellow drizzle or sauce are either of the two classic accompaniments to asparagus, then hollandaise (as in eggs Benedict) or butter sauces won't be best made in an oven unless the dishes are being finished or kept "warm" [sic] in the oven. Those things on the top looked like roasted baby bunnies until I saw otherwise on the enlarged photo!

Comment: I am now fairly certain that this is not an hollandaise sauce (the texture is too runny) but more likely to be melted butter, perhaps with flecks of something green. Herb butter?

Comment: @PeterPoint - I'm pretty sure it would have to be a keep-warm situation, since I don't think they would have baked well together - too much mass of food and not enough air circulation would slow everything while it heated, not to mention no top browning on the lower dishes.  The asparagus looks tasty but also so *awkward* to serve and eat, though, like it won't stick to the bread.  And yeah, it looks thin so I was thinking herb or garlic butter and cheese with the asparagus,

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct. Furthermore, that space age kitchen appliance looks more likely to be found in a high-end restaurant than a domestic kitchen of the rank and file out there.